# Trying to convert Jquery Sortable to Kendo Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, kendo-sortable

I am not able to find Rearrange event and refreshPositions method in kendo sortable which is available in Jquery sortable.

```
$.ui.sortable.prototype._rearrange = function (event, i) {
                            this.refreshPositions();
                    });
```